# 1 - 1 Composite relationship class set to notify "both" not updating origin when editing destination

Tags: relationship-class, origin-destination

I have two spatial feature classes and want to have the spatial edits reflected in both feature classes when editing either the origin or destination. I have set up a composite relationship with a 1-1 relationship and notifications set to both. When editing the origin the destination changes with it ( I believe this is default with composites set to forwarding). Problem is, when editing the destination, the edits are not reflected in the origin. I thought if set to both this would work out.

Comment: What software are you using? The situation you describe is a 2-way replica which historically is only available in Esri with two instances of SDE, I'm not sure how you would do this in Esri with the demise of SDE. 2-way replicas are by no means automatic and need to be *reconciled* on a regular basis to allow the edits slave->master and master->slave to be propagated, along with conflict resolution.

Comment: Just because SDE is gone doesn't mean that enterprise geodatabase replication no longer exists.